# Disable text on top of my spinner

Tags: android, xamarin, spinner

This is my spinner init code:

```
private void InitSpinner()
{
    spnAvatar = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.btn_avatarProfile);

    var adapter = ArrayAdapter.CreateFromResource(
            this, Resource.Array.planets_array, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem);

    adapter.SetDropDownViewResource(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);
    spnAvatar.Adapter = adapter;

    spnAvatar.ItemSelected += delegate
    {
        Toast.MakeText(this, "Spinner Info Changed", ToastLength.Long).Show();
    };
}
```

For some reason, my spinner always displays the text of the chosen item from the drop down menu on top of the background resource that my spinner is using. This is the result:

[image]

It streches my profile phote and looks stupid.
How do I disable that?

Comment: send screenshot of full screen and layout. did u set imageView in spinner custom view?

Comment: Which is your spinner ? If you don't need your spinner display text, why did you use it ?

Comment: where it says "show my photo". i want a little menu to chose from a few options when clicked upon. i though a spinner was as good idea. but maybe a alert will do ...

Comment: okay i just went for an alert and that made everything a lot smoother. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a spinner, I went with this:

```
    private void AlertForFacebook()
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.SetPositiveButton("Change Picture", (senderAlert, args) =>
        {

        });

        alert.SetNeutralButton("Show Picture", (senderAlert, args) =>
        {

        });

        Dialog dialog = alert.Create();
        dialog.Show();
    }
```

Looks a lot better in HOLO LIGHT theme :)